# Access files over network path from web application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web application deployed over two load balanced servers, Out of which one acts as a repository of all images used for application. Path similar to below exists on say  "webserver1"

```
C:\inetpub\Images\
```

Images folder is shared with "EveryOne" permission to FullControl.

Now on "webserver2" , I add a virtual directory which points to "\webserver1\Images"
This can be accessed as expected using windows+r on webserver 2.

Although in My application which hosted on webserver2 IIS.
I get error which say "File not found \webserver\images\filename"

I believe the permissions should be already taken care of by assigning Everyone?

Can someone help?

UPDATE:
Code used to read file from webserver2 is

```
Server.MapPath(filename)
```

filename is \images\filename which transforms to \webserver1\images\filename
and throws file not found error

Exception after putting some variables in exception throw:

mappath is \Webserver2\ProductImages..  filename is /images/ProductImages/..

Exception thrown is "\Webserver2\ProductImages.." file not found IO Exception

Comment: When on webserver2, can you browse to the shared folder and view images using Windows Explorer?

Comment: Yes I can access shared folder from webserver2

Comment: can you show the code in regards to how you are reading the file Path are you familiar with `Server.MapPath`

Comment: I have updated the description with information

Comment: If `filename` has `\images\filename` stored in it and your running that on server2 then it does not transform into `\\webserver1\...`  Could you update your question with the actual error message, actual code and actual values in the variables you are using?  This doesn't look right at all.

Comment: Instead of using \\machine\share path, have you tried mapping the network drive, so you would access it from say K:\images ?

Comment: I think that \\machinename is being converted to \machinename since the \ character is an escape character so try adding either @"\\" or "\\\\"